# How can I store multiple numpy vectors conveniently?

Tags: python, list, numpy

My car has 4 wheels and I want to caculate the weight in Newtons on each of the wheels given a mass and center of gravity. I want to store the vectors from origin to each of the 4 wheels conveniently so that I can use the cross product of numpy. Currently I have this:

```
location_wheel = [np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([]), np.array([])]
```

Where the first array would be the front left wheel, second one the front right one etc.
I feel like there's a better or more convenient  way to do this. Got any suggestions?

I also thought of making 4 separate variables, though that made even less sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could also try to have a 2d np array like this.

```
arr = np.array([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9], [10, 11, 12]])
```

or

```
arr = np.ndarray(shape=(x,y), dtype=float)
```

Comment: Oh yeah, that's right. That looks better already! Thanks

Comment: Why should I use np array instead of np nDarray? Does it matter?